# How to get entire list of nested inner list groups, and add sort & limit to them. MongoDB query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, limit

I have the following model of an object called EvaluationsGroup in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "5fecfb83d61ae459df1bceda",
    "Status" : "noDataFound",
    "Evaluations" : [ 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2020-12-30T22:13:21.168Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 2.0
        }
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2020-12-30T22:13:15.168Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 3.0,
             (... several other properties)
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is get the entire list of all inner `Evaluations` of all the 'EvaluationsGroups' indistinctively, sort them by `EvaluatedAt` date, and limit the results for paging.

How would I make such a query in mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Evaluations` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object in root
- `$sort` by `EvaluatedAt` date in descending order
- `$skip` number of documents for pagination
- `$limit` number of documents

```
let page = 0;
let limit = 10;
let skip = page*limit;
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Evaluations: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Evaluations" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Evaluations" } },
  { $sort: { EvaluatedAt: -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a8AiMaztPg8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) property in mongodb

> ```
> db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [ 
>     { $unwind : "$Evaluations" },
>     { $sort: { "Evaluations.EvaluatedAt": 1 } },
>     { $limit: 10 }
> ] )
> ```

The above code has 3 stage pipeline

•   Stage 1 : Unwind the array into individual Object - [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

•   Stage 2 : Sort the array based on the `Evaluations.EvaluatedAt` property  - [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

•   Stage 3 : Set the limit range - [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)